# ¿Cómo pasar a una api una hastable transformando datos vmware powershell?

Tags: powershell, hash, vmware

Tengo una función que se ejecuta de la siguiente forma:

```
New-XVCMRequest xxxxxxx    -NetworkMapping @{"Infra (Network)"="Infra (DistributedVirtualPortgroup);"Infra2 (Network)"="Infra2 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)";"Infra3 (Network)"="Infra3 (DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}
```

Mi idea es reemplazar el **networkmaping** con un **hastable** que armo dinámicamente. Tengo hecha un **forearch** que arma un **hashtable** de la siguiente forma:

```
$vm2 = Get-VM -Name "xxx"
$networkDetails2 = $vm2 | Get-NetworkAdapter
$hash = $null
$hash = @{}
 foreach ($net in $networkDetails2) {

 $hash.add($net.Networkname + '(Network)',$net.Networkname + '(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)' )

}
```

El problema es que **'$hash'** cuando lo presento de la forma:

```
New-XVCMRequest xxxxxxx     -NetworkMapping $hash
```

Lo envía con dos puntos en vez de '=' y con ',' en vez de ';'.

**Ejemplo que no funciona**
Infra2(Network)":"Infra2(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)","Infra(Network)":"Infra(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}

**Como debería mandar el hash**
Infra2(Network)"="Infra2(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)";"Infra(Network)"="Infra(DistributedVirtualPortgroup)"}